# constraints are not behaving consistently when set conditionally

Tags: swift, uitableview, constraints

I have a problem when I set a constraint conditionally for a custom table cell.  For example, I have two UIImageViews in a custom table cell. These are constrained to each other but the offset is conditional on the cell contents.

When I set up the UITableView, everything appears fine but as I scroll through the cells, the constraints stop working and the images are jumping around.  My code looks like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    if myArray[indexPath.row] == "Farmyard" {
        cell.image1.image = UIImage(named: "Barn")
        cell.image2.image = UIImage(named: "Tractor")
        // offset +10
        cell.image2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.image1.centerXAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    } else if myArray[indexPath.row] == "Factory" {
        cell.image1.image = UIImage(named: "Warehouse")
        cell.image2.image = UIImage(named: "Truck")
        // offset +20
        cell.image2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.image1.centerXAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    }
    return cell
}

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var image1: UIImageView!
    var image2: UIImageView!
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        image1 = UIImageView()
        contentView.addSubview(image1)
        image1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image2 = UIImageView()
        contentView.addSubview(image2)
        image2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:)")
    }
}
```

It looks like the conditional constraints are lost as I scroll through the tableview.  As I scroll up and down, I see that more and more of the images are in the wrong position.  Has anyone also had this problem or know another way to set conditional constraints with a custom cell?  I only see this problem when I set a constraint from the `cellForRowAt` method.  Constraints set up from within the custom cell behave as expected.  I want to use several images and labels eventually, so setting up multiple custom cells is not an option.

Comment: can you share your whole code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding following lines before returning the cell:

```
cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

I thinks the layout changes of some cells are discarded while scrolling since the cells are reused.

Comment: Thanks for coming back.  I decided after running several experiments this approach will not work so I've abandoned this part of my design